# Servidor Rails Windows se queda iniciando

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Instalé Ruby 2.6.4 y Rails 6.0 en Windows.  Creé un nuevo proyecto con Rails new blog.  Cuando terminó entré a la carpeta blog y ejecuté Rails s y el servidor trata de iniciar y se queda intentando sin mostrar ningún error, pero nunca inicia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las versiones exactas de Ruby y Rails son:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Reviso en la carpeta log a ver si me dice algo, pero el archivo development.log está vacío.

¿Alguien sabe qué puede estar pasando?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Has revisado el administrador de tareas para revisar el uso de CPU del proceso? hay alguna posibilidad que el puerto 3000 esté ocupado por otro proceso? prueba con `rails s -p 3001`

Comment: Ya había intentado usar otro puerto y pasa lo mismo.

Comment: No tengo mucha experiencia corriendo rails en windows, quizás tengas algún programa que lo esté bloqueando por alguna razón, o el firewall, lo desconozco. No relacionado, pero si estás iniciándote en Rails, podrías considerar usar una máquina con linux que eventualmente te dará muchos menos problemas para correr rails en general. Si instalarlo no es una opción, puedes usar una máquina virtual en windows o quizás correr tu ambiente de desarrollo en un container docker... se que se escapa un poco de lo que quieres ahora mismo, pero a la larga puede evitarte dolores de cabeza. Saludos

Comment: Definitivamente fue imposible hacer que funcionara, sin embargo en otro equipo sí funciona.  Al final tuve que desinstalar Rails 6 y dejar la versión 5.2.3, pero me pierdo de las nuevas funcionalidades de la versión 6.  Será esperar que liberen un nuevo release.